# Add dev machine ip, git root path, and current branch automatically in git commit with hook

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

I often forget from which machine, which local git repository, and which branch a gerrit change was submitted. Is there a way to add such information automatically to every git commit message, perhaps through a pre-commit hook? Thanks!

Comment: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: was on my phone and felt the one-sentence answer as not good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.git/hooks/pre-commit` hooks cannot act on the commit message (it isn't formed when they run) but there are a set of hooks which do act on the commit message:

From [the git hooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

- `commit-msg`: The commit-msg hook takes one parameter, which again is the path to a temporary file that contains the commit message written by the developer. If this script exits non-zero, Git aborts the commit process, so you can use it to validate your project state or commit message before allowing a commit to go through
- `prepare-commit-msg`: The prepare-commit-msg hook is run before the commit message editor is fired up but after the default message is created. It lets you edit the default message before the commit author sees it

in particular, your modifications would happen in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook probably